# Auth on ubuntu store problems

Tags: software-installation

In Ubuntu 18.04,
when authenticating, I enter my username and password but it does nothing.

[image]

Comment: Clearer please, what is do nothing?? does nothing when what?? when you press continue button??? after how much time waiting??

Comment: Literally nothing I can click it multiple times in a row and nothing, no loading no error nothing. It seems the button has no function.

Comment: Did you try the enter key of your keyboard after entering password or email address???